# SQL / BigQuery- How to group by chain of pairs in different columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, graph-theory, recursive-query

I am trying to aggregate rows on a chain of pairs. For example, given table:

```
pair0 | pair1
  a      z
  b      a
  c      b
  d      b
  m      n
  z      y
```

Returns:

```
matches
[a, z, b, c, d, y]
[m, n]
```

where order of the pairs doesn't matter.

I've tried joining the table on itself, but am unable to aggregate in this way without putting the join in the loop, for the max number of possible combinations.

```
SELECT
   [a.pair0, a.pair1, b.pair0, b.pair1] as matches
FROM pairs a
LEFT JOIN pairs b
ON a.pair0 = b.pair1
GROUP BY
   matches
```

and then would filter matches for distinct. but, this solution only works if the chain is limited to two rows. In the example above, the chain extends for 5 rows. Grouping by an array also is not allowed.

Comment: This is a kind of graph traversal problem. In SQL it is usually solved with recursive queries, which I think BigQuery does not support. Just in case, do you have another database at hand?

Comment: BigQuery does support recursive queries! Search here for 'with recursive' on google-bigquery tag - I (and others) have answered plenty of similar (if not the exact same) questions!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: I didn't know that it had been added... that's really good news! I gave it a shot. And while I'm at it, here are my 2 cents: why don't we have a BQ fiddle available for everyone to play in, as we do for many  other major databases (db-fiddle and the like)?

Comment: @GMB - try [BigQuery Sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox) :o)

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery supports recursive queries: yay! With this feature at hand, we can try and solve this graph-walking problem.

The idea is to start by generating  all possible edges, and then recursively query traverse the graph, while taking care of not visiting the same node twice. Once all paths are visited, we can identify to which group each node belongs by looking at the aggregated list of its visited nodes.

```
with recursive 
    edges as (
        select x.pair0, x.pair1
        from pairs p
        cross join lateral (
            select p.pair0, p.pair1 union all select p.pair1, p.pair0
        ) x(pair0, pair1)
    ),
    cte as (
        select pair0, pair1, [ pair1 ] visited
        from edges
        union all
        select c.pair0, e.pair1, array_concat(c.visited, [ e.pair1 ] )
        from cte c
        inner join edges e on e.pair0 = c.pair1 and e.pair1 not in unnest(c.visited)
    ),
    res as (
        select pair0, array_agg(distinct pair1 order by pair1) grp
        from cte
        group by pair0
    )
select distinct grp from res
```